# What causes "Request was aborted after waiting too long to attempt to service your request"?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

What causes "Request was aborted after waiting too long to attempt to service your request"?

It seems the result of some sort of internal timeout, but I don't know where this is configured.
We're currently using autoscaling, and that error was the result of a temporary increase in the number of tasks in our taskqueue. Shouldn't autoscaling have created more instances to handle that request?

Also, if a task in Cloud Tasks fails with "Request was aborted after waiting too long to attempt to service your request", is that task retried, or is it removed from the queue?

Edit: I found the problem.
This was the configuration for scailing in our app.yaml:

```
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 2
```

Comment: This is documented here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/how-requests-are-handled

Comment: Hello, Could you expand how often do you see this error showing up?
Also, I believe that this could be an error caused by the scaling options, although it can also be generated for some memory issues... I believe that this could be a configuration issue, so I would suggest to check your service dashboards and try to check out if you identify some scaling issues or if this happens when the service is under heavy load of requests.

Comment: It's quite rare for it to happen. I don't think resource usage (such as memory and CPU) was high at the time, but we did have quite a few tasks (possibly a couple of thousand) in the tasksqueue.

Comment: I'm thinking that this could have something to do with your scaling configuration, it would be great if you could review this documentation about how instances are managed by app engine, maybe the issue is that there are not enough instances to serve these requests and as you say that this are not common it makes me think that it could be a request that is beginning the scaling up of the instances or... it could be a simple error of GAE as sometimes it can fail, but I believe that's why they have SLAs

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed

Comment: See this support ticket: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172047600

Answer (score 3):

I found this when I was proxying to view a munin node with many graphs on an f1-micro backend. Responses will fail with a 529 error if they are waiting for longer than `(min|max)_pending_latency` - probably it is trying to create a new instance, because the minimum is violated, but finds it cannot.

The default appears to be 5s. You can set it in `app.yaml` to a max of 15s.

```
automatic_scaling:
  min_pending_latency: 15s
  max_pending_latency: 15s
```

Once I did that I stopped getting the errors for requests waiting for 6s. Of course, I'm sure Google would prefer you increase the number of scaling instances, or use a faster node. But maybe you only want to scale to one or two, or 15s is an acceptable latency for what you're trying to do.

For reference, my full `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: php81
service: munin
instance_class: F1

automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1
  min_instances: 0
  target_cpu_utilization: 0.95
  target_throughput_utilization: 0.95
  max_concurrent_requests: 80
  max_pending_latency: 15s

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: auto
  secure: always
```

You can experiment with settings like `min_pending_latency: 5s` and `max_pending_latency: 10s` but in that case you probably want `max_instances: 2` and `min_instances: 1`.

I still use PHP 8.1 even though 8.2 is out because [PHP 8.1 uses Ubuntu 22.04](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/lifecycle/support-schedule#php) and I found it flaky in comparison, at least for my use-case - perhaps it's too heavy for the default instance.