# Google App Engine - Getting lots of Request was aborted errors

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have multiple applications running on Google App Engine, using Java.  In the last month I have been getting a lot of "Request was aborted after waiting too long to attempt to service your request" errors occurring.  The logline for the errors show them happening after about 25ms to 1.7 seconds.  I tried setting the `min-idle-instances` to 1 but this made no difference to the number of error.

Other answers I have seen just seem to say to set the `min-idle-instances` so aren't much help

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @user1150103 I would recommend you to check the options and solutions informed in this other Community question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60067155/what-causes-request-was-aborted-after-waiting-too-long-to-attempt-to-service-yo). There are some possible solutions that might help you, that don't involve the setting `min-idle-instances`. If even this way, you are still facing the problem, I would recommend you to reach out directly to [Google Support](https://cloud.google.com/support), so they can check directly what is causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks @gso_gabriel, I'll do that

Comment: Hi gso_gabriel, that worked for a couple of days then I suddenly got a whole lot of errors this morning :(.  It's not quite as bad as before so definitely a help.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happens when there is a sudden increase on the QPS or traffic, so in that case, In GAE instance some requests might have to wait for available instances to handle them, internally there is a 10-second limit that if the instance is not able to serve the request it will throw the message "**Request was aborted after waiting too long to attempt to service your request**". We too tried min-idle-instance but that won't solve this type of problem.
We have already raised the ticket for this issue Google has been working on this one 
[image: Google Update April 2020] [image: Google Update May First Week of 2020]
Will update here Whenever google resolves this issue.

Comment: Thanks @Thilak, that sounds like my issue.  Hopefully see an end to this on the 5th May

Comment: I've opened a feature request to allow the 10 second timeout to be customizable: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172047600